# Another old Soviet Paper

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, specific-reference

I'm interested in a paper by Prof. E.E. Nikitin from $1962$. The reference from the book is:

> "E.E. Nikitin: Opt. Spektrosk. $13$, $761$ ($1962$) [English transl.: Opt. Spectrosc. USSR $13$,$431$ ($1962$)]"

I haven't had any luck with either the Russian version or the English translation since the oldest volume on Springer is from $2000$. I was only able to find a paper from the Discussions of the Faraday Society, but I wanted to read the original reference.

So if anyone has a clue on where to look, I'll highly appreciate it.

Edit: Following the advice from the comments I asked both the librarian at my institution and the librarian at my local library. My university does not have it and the people from my local library haven't responded to my query. We requested an interlibrary loan, but I haven't received any responses, to date.

Comment: Talk to your local librarian, they are experts in finding these old papers.

Comment: [Related discussion on Meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4490/how-should-we-handle-how-to-find-a-specific-reference-requests).

Comment: The Worldcat page for the Russian-language version is [here](https://www.worldcat.org/title/optika-i-spektroskopija/oclc/637449682), and (at least in my location) it shows libraries with copies. But as mentioned above, if you are at a university then you already have a dedicated professional whose job is to connect you with the literature you need (a.k.a. your librarian), so go talk with them. Almost certainly, the successful approach will be an electronic inter-library loan from somewhere that does have it, and this needs to go through your librarian.